# How to show Header without show Cell in CollectionView iOS Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, header, footer, collectionview

I have collection view with *Cell*,*Header* and *Footer*. some of indexes in my datasource not have object that contains cell data, Therefore I want to not show cell for that indexes.
I tried to set `return nil` in **cellForItemAt** but it's not possible.
Help me to fix this.

Comment: Just return 0 in `numberOfRowsForSection`? I think header still showing if you have that section but no cell

Comment: @Tj3n You mean `numberOfItemsInSection`.

Comment: if has no data, just set the `sizeForItem` (sorry I don't remember the exactly name) in the delegate to `CGRect.zero`

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for correction, for `collectionView` it is `numberOfItemsInSection `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return `0` in `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)`.